# Automatically close of Dialog box without any click in Android app

Tags: android, android-dialog

Can we create an Alert Dialog box which will appear after doing some activity and automatically get closed without any click (whether any button click or click outside the alert dialog box)?
Like, if we can add some delay to the dialog box to close after some specified seconds. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way to automatically close the alert dialog box would be to use Handler to delay the Dialog box.

Example:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Here 2000 specifies number of milliseconds of delaying the Alert dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html
This should do the job. A toast does not need a click, and can be timed.

Comment: Thanks... I guess it will definitely serve my purpose... :)

Comment: Well, I guess better way to delay the dialog box close is to use Handler rather than using Toast. but yes, Thanks for your immediate help.